# visual studio 2012 c++ no cout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to learn c++ but a simple method like "cout" and "cin" does not exist
this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout>>"hello";
    return 0;
}
```

there is an error that says "error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier"

and "IntelliSense: identifier "cout" is undefined"

Comment: Your angle brackets are backwards. Try `std::cout << "hello"`.

Comment: `cout` is in the `std` namespace. Try `std::cout << "hello";`

Comment: You're missing `std::` and you mixed up `>>` and `<<`.

Comment: I just open a project in visual studio 2012. I only added the: cout<<"hello";

Comment: @user2302416: Yes, and that's why it's not working. Change `cout<<"hello";` to `std::cout << "hello";` -- or, better yet, `std::cout << "hello\n";`. You *could* drop the `std::` by adding `using namespace std;`; you'll see a lot of code that does that, but it's often considered to be a bad habit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cout` is declared in the `std` namespace:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

You're also doing it wrong.  Note how I have the angle brackets aboove.

Comment: `_t` in front of `main()` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:L  This is a Windows thing.

Comment: is there a thing that I can use instead of visual studio 2012 to learn c++?

Comment: @user2302416:  Under Windows?

Comment: @user2302416 MinGW is a good compiler for Windows, along with either Qt Creator or Code Blocks.

Comment: You can also use VS2012 and write Standard code.  Just create a Win32 console project, forget all the precompiled header stuff, and write a main.cpp from scratch in an empty project.  I think you'll be hard pressed to find a compiler that is as powerful and easy to use as VS.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#include <iostream>` to `stdafx.h`. I was having trouble with that and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `using namespace std;` may help, and also do `cout << "hello"` not `>>`.

Comment: what's bad at using a namespace?

Comment: `using namespace std` can create many more problems than it solves, especially when done in a header file.

Comment: @IosifM. It's considered bad for [many, many reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Praetorian, I agree that "collisions" may occur on "custom-made" namespaces, but still... namespace std?

Comment: It wasn't, but you did not explain how doing `using namespace std` can be a problem, even in a source file, so to a newbie this could be taken as *the* solution.  Hence you are effectively suggesting that this is an appropriate solution in all contexts, which it's not.

Comment: Don't teach bad habits regardless of it. Namespace pollution is bad. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: pulling in a full namespace for something this simple is plainly overkill anyways.

Comment: It's even worse with `namespace std` because it contains all sorts of generic sounding names, such as `find` or `accumulate` (or practically anything from `<algorithm>`)

Comment: OK, I guess you've proven your point pretty well :). Was just curious why it's good to avoid namespaces.

Comment: so I should'nt use the namespace?

Comment: @user2302416: No, you should not use a `using namespace` declaration until you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: for std specifically you're pretty much always better off calling the namespace directly as needed because of the sheer amount of different functions that it implements....otherwise there's always the old C way of using printf instead of cout.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is in `std` so you to have use `using namespace std`. And for `cout` operator is like `<<`. `>>`  this is for input i.e `cin`.

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include "iostream";
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout<<"hello";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```